Did the Descartes-Euler conjecture influence Poincaré's theory of homology?
What is the Descartes-Euler Conjecture?

all simply-connected polyhedra with simply-connected faces are Eulerian $V-E+F=2$.
Additional explanation: The lemma which was falsified by the ring-shaped face was not -as you seem to think- that 'all faces are triangular' but that 'any face dissected by a diagonal edge falls into two pieces'. It is this lemma which I turn into a condition. Calling the faces which satisfy it 'simply-connected', I can offer a second improvement on my original conjecture. (page 36 in this book)
Definition P. A polyhedron is a system of polygons for which the equation $V-E+F=2$ holds.
Obviously, in the very narrow domain described by Definition P. The Descartes-Euler conjecture was trivially satisfied as the Definition P. (In this file's page 9~10)

Cut to the chase
I read the book Proofs and refutations: The logic of mathematical discovery by Imre Lakatos. However, as I read this book, I thought that Poincaré may have been an opportunity to come up with the idea of ​​homology in the process of proving the Descartes-Euler conjecture. From now on, I will write about the reasons for why I thought as above.
Reasons


The next term to be elucidated is 'bound'. I shall say that a $k$-circuit bounds, if it is the boundary of a $(k+1)$-chain. (page 113 in this book)

You are wrong. I demand that all the circuits should bound: even the 0-circuits. I have translated 'simply-connectedness of a polyhedron' into 'all 1-circuits and 2-circuits bound'; and 'simply-connectedness of the faces' into 'all 0-circuits bound'. (page 114 in this book)

The original motivation for defining homology groups was the observation that two shapes can be distinguished by examining their holes. For instance, a circle is not a disk because the circle has a hole through it while the disk is solid, and the ordinary sphere is not a circle because the sphere encloses a two-dimensional hole while the circle encloses a one-dimensional hole. However, because a hole is "not there", it is not immediately obvious how to define a hole or how to distinguish different kinds of holes. Homology was originally a rigorous mathematical method for defining and categorizing holes in a manifold. Loosely speaking, a cycle is a closed submanifold, a boundary is a cycle which is also the boundary of a submanifold, and a homology class (which represents a hole) is an equivalence class of cycles modulo boundaries. A homology class is thus represented by a cycle which is not the boundary of any submanifold: the cycle represents a hole, namely a hypothetical manifold whose boundary would be that cycle, but which is "not there". (In wikipedia)



Of course, the wikipedia article I linked also says that the homology theory was influenced by the Betti number, and I also do not want to say that the Descartes-Euler conjecture completely contributed to the creation of the homology theory. I'm just curious as to whether this is one of the problems that influenced Poincaré and led to the emergence of homology theory.
Edit: I additionally read this paper, Poincaré's Analysis Situs.

He generalizes the Euler polyhedron formula to arbitrary dimensions and situates it in his homology theory. (in this pdf file's page 10)
Could not the method of M. Klein be extended to the group of n
variables, or any continuous group? I have not been able to succeed so far, but I have thought a great deal about the question and it seems to me that the solution must depend on a problem of Analysis situs and that the generalization of celebrated Euler polyhedron theorem must play a role. (in this pdf file's page 23)

Through Poincaré's paper Analysis Situs, we can see that Poincaré attempted to solve Euler's polyhedron theorem through homology theory. And according to page 120 of the book Proofs and refutations: The logic of mathematical discovery seen above, the following text appears:

And while we have difficulties in applying Jordan's intuitive (i.e. non-star-intuitive) concept of simply-connectedness of the polyhedron to star-polyhedra, in the Poincaré translation these difficulties disappear.

From the above article, we can see that Poincaré's proof of the Descartes-Euler conjecture is a generalization of the original Euler polyhedron theorem.

Can you edit in a description of the Descartes-Euler conjecture?

@Vincent Hello, I know Descartes-Euler conjecture : all simply-connected polyhedra with simply-connected faces are Eulerian $V-E+F=2$
